# mentions_timeline() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, tweepy

I can't seem to be getting this to work. I've watched so many videos and have read through docs. I just can NOT get this working. I'm trying to get my Twitter bot working

**Code**

```py
FILE_NAME = 'last_seen.txt'

def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id

def store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, last_seen_id):
    file_write = open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
    file_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    file_write.close()
    return

def reply():
    tweets = api.mentions_timeline(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended')
    for tweet in reversed(tweets):
        if '@MrGoodnightBot' in tweet.full_text.lower():
            print(str(tweet.id) + ' - ' + tweet.full_text)
            api.update_status("@" + tweet.user.screen_name + " testing auto reply/like/retweet", tweet.id)
            api.create_favorite(tweet.id)
            api.retweet(tweet.id)
            api.create_friendship(tweet.user.id)
            store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, tweet.id)

while True:
    reply()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Error**

```
  File "E:\Twitter Bot\bot.py", line 29, in reply
    tweets = api.mentions_timeline(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 33, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: mentions_timeline() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Hmm, i can't seem to find the argument `tweet_mode` in the tweepy [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=mentions_timeline#tweepy.API.mentions_timeline) for `mentions_timeline`. Are you sure you're using it correctly? Would also be helpful if you mention what sources you're referring to in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) changed [`API.mentions_timeline`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/api.html#tweepy.API.mentions_timeline) to not accept any positional arguments.
The 1 positional argument being referred to in the error is `self`.
You can pass `read_last_seen(FILE_NAME)` as the `since_id` keyword argument instead.

This is also covered in [a FAQ section in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-am-i-getting-a-typeerror-about-an-api-method-taking-1-positional-argument-but-given-2).

Answer (score 0):

There's some code missing so I need to make an assumption but from the [documentation on tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#tweepy.API.mentions_timeline) the function signature for `mentions_timeline` is:

```py
API.mentions_timeline(*, count, since_id, max_id, trim_user, include_entities)
```

This `*` indicates that all arguments after the symbol **have** to be passed as key word arguments. E.g. this should normally work:

```py
tweets = api.mentions_timeline(count=read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended')
```

*But* the signature does not indicate a `tweet_mode` exists?

Comment: `tweet_mode` is for [extended Tweets](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/extended_tweets.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue I passed since_id = read_last_seen(FILE_NAME) and it worked